# Image preview not generated on node edit page

Tags: media

My content type has field type "Image" and using "Media selector" to upload images.

Images are uploaded properly but not previewed at the same time on node add/edit page. I can check that preview is generated with firebug.

If I go to library then again preview not displayed but after saving node it is displaying.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Which image style you are using to show preview image? Is that image style really exist or it may be deleted?

Comment: I made sure image style exists. Another thing I noticed was Image is not loaded even on page when first time page loads. If we come back to that page after some clicks, it is present there.

Comment: I get it resolved by removing a blank line before <?php tag with index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any blank line before opening or after closing php tags. The chances of having it with index.php, template.php,settings.php etc. files